# How to get around strptime error, want to sort on a datetime string in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, datetime

I'm building a script to analyse performance data output from multiple log files. I managed to create a list of lists with all events and their timestamps, next step I need to sort this list of lists on the timestamp per event. So far so good I googled myself to this:

```
sorted_list = sorted(samplesList, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[2], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S,%f'))
```

and then the following error shows, leaving me with no clues how to solve and no hits on google on this specfic error:

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not
>   builtin_function_or_method

Previously I had a mistake (. and ,) in the formatting and then it really looked promissing:

> ValueError: time data '2017-10-02T11:03:49,167' does not match format
>   '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'

Which showed me that at least i fed it with the correct data.

Any hints on how to work around?

Comment: the punctuation mark before `%f` is a period, but the time data has it as a comma. Change that, and it should work.

Comment: thanks but i got around that one, its about the first error

Comment: I think i found the solution myself by converting the timestamps to epochs